# Why doesn't the title of a link show when using a <strong> tag inside it

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

### Code

Here is the HTML code:

```
<li>
  <a href="./hacks/hacks.html" title="Break the rules with techniques, not malicious invasion into computer and destroy the computer network.">
    <strong>HACKS</strong>
  </a> -
  <em>Break the rules with techniques, not malicious invasion into computer and destroy the computer network.</em>
</li>
```

### Problem

The problem is when I put mouse focus on the link, the **title** (*Break the rules with techniques, not malicious invasion into computer and destroy the computer network.*) won't show up. when I delete the `<strong></strong>` between **HACKS**, it works. (**IE 10**)

### Screenshots

- Screenshot - works in IE 10 without `<strong></strong>` [image: Title works without strong]  [title-works-without-strong]
- Screenshot - doesn't works in IE 10 with `<strong><strong>`  [image: Title doesn't work with strong]

After I change the browser to **Chrome 27**, the **title** worked.

Guys, any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's about moving the strong outside the anchor:

```
<li>
  <strong><a href="./hacks/hacks.html" title="Break the rules with techniques, not malicious invasion into computer and destroy the computer network.">
    HACKS
  </a></strong> -
  <em>Break the rules with techniques, not malicious invasion into computer and destroy the computer network.</em>
</li>
```

Tested on IE7

Comment: Now try putting the title to the strong. It doesn't. :)

Comment: What do you mean praveen? How do I put the title to the strong?

Answer (score 0):

put it like this.

```
<a href="..hacks\hack.html">PUT YOUR TITLE HERE</a>
```

you don't need a title tag like you have. put the title for the link in between the a tag and the end a tag.
hope that helped.